# std::async doesn't work asynchronously

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

I have the following very simple code:

```
void TestSleep()
{
    std::cout << "TestSleep " << std::endl;
    sleep(10);
    std::cout << "TestSleep Ok" << std::endl;

}

void TestAsync()
{
    std::cout << "TestAsync" << std::endl;
    std::async(std::launch::async, TestSleep);
    std::cout << "TestAsync ok!!!" << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
    TestAsync();
    return 0;
}
```

Since I use `std::launch::async` I expect that `TestSleep()` will be run asynchronously and I will have the following output:

```
TestAsync
TestAsync ok!!!
TestSleep 
TestSleep Ok
```

But really I have the output for synchronous run:

```
TestAsync
TestSleep 
TestSleep Ok
TestAsync ok!!!
```

Could you explain why and how to make `TestSleep` call really asynchronously.

Answer (score 15):

From [this `std::async` reference notes section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async#Notes)

> If the `std::future` obtained from `std::async` is not moved from or bound to a reference, the destructor of the `std::future` will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes, essentially making code ... synchronous

This is what happens here. Since you don't store the future that `std::async` returns, it will be destructed at the end of the expression (which is the `std::async` call) and that will block until the thread finishes.

If you do e.g.

```
auto f = std::async(...);
```

then the destruction of `f` at the end of `TestAsync` will block, and the text `"TestAsync ok!!!"` should be printed before `"TestSleep Ok"`.

Comment: Also, making the asynchronous function void seems to cause problems, perhaps for the same reason. Better to have it return something.

Comment: @cag51 `std::async` is really more about creating some asynchronous work that give a result. If you just want to do some generic work that doesn't return a result it might be better with a thread.

Answer (score 6):

[`std::async()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) returns an instance of [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future). If you look at the documentation for [`std::future`'s destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future), it says the following:

> these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, except that it may block if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state.

You aren't storing the return value of `std::async()` into a local variable, but that value is still created and must be destroyed. Since the destructor will block until your function returns, this makes it synchronous.

If you change `TestAsync()` to return the `std::future()` created by `std::async()`, then it should be asynchronous.