# std::async causes deadlock?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, std

I was trying to use std::async in a heavy workload application to improve the performance but I encountered deadlock from time to time. I debugged for a very long time and I am almost certain that my code was fine and it seemed something wrong with std library.

So I wrote a simple test program to testify:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <iomanip>

std::atomic_long numbers[6];

void add(std::atomic_long& n)
{
    ++n;
}

void func2(std::atomic_long& n)
{
    for (auto i = 0L; i < 1000000000000L; ++i)
    {
        std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {add(n);});   // Small task, I want to run them simultaneously
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> results;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        auto& n = numbers[i];
        results.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&n] {func2(n);}));
    }

    while (true)
    {
        sleep(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            std::cout << std::setw(20) << numbers[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto& r : results)
    {
        r.wait();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program will produce output like this:

```
              763700               779819               754005               763287               767713               748994 
              768822               785172               759678               769393               772956               754469 
              773529               789382               763524               772704               776398               757864 
              778560               794419               768580               777507               781542               762991 
              782056               795578               771704               780554               784865               766162 
              801633               812610               788111               802617               803661               784894
```

After a time (minutes or hours), if there was a deadlock, the output will be like this:

```
             4435337              4452421              4507907              4501378              2549550              4462899 
             4441213              4457648              4514424              4506626              2549550              4468019 
             4446301              4462675              4519272              4511889              2549550              4473266 
             4453940              4470304              4526382              4519513              2549550              4480872 
             4461095              4477708              4533272              4526901              2549550              4488313 
             4470974              4488287              4543442              4537286              2549550              4498733
```

**The fifth column was frozen.**

After one day, it became this:

```
            23934912             23967635             24007250             23931203              2549550           3249788689 
            23934912             23967635             24007250             23931203              2549550           3249816818 
            23934912             23967635             24007250             23931203              2549550           3249835009 
            23934912             23967635             24007250             23931203              2549550           3249860262 
            23934912             23967635             24007250             23931203              2549550           3249894331
```

Almost all columns froze except last column. It look really odd.

I ran it on Linux, macOS, FreeBSD, and the result was:

- macOS:10.15.2, Clang:11.0.0, no deadlock
- FreeBSD:12.0, Clang:6.0.1, deadlock
- Linux: ubuntu 5.0.0-37, g++:7.4.0, no deadlock
- Linux: ubuntu 4.4.0-21, Clang:3.8.0, deadlock

In the gdb, the call stack was:

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 10 (LWP 100467 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080025c630 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff4ad57000

Thread 9 (LWP 100464 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080046fafa in _umtx_op () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x0000000800264912 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x000000080031f9f9 in std::__1::mutex::unlock() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#3  0x00000008002e8f55 in std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::set_value() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x00000000002053e1 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::__execute() ()
#5  0x0000000000205763 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >*> >(void*) ()
#6  0x000000080025c776 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff6944a000

Thread 8 (LWP 100431 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080046fafa in _umtx_op () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x0000000800264912 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x000000080031f9f9 in std::__1::mutex::unlock() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#3  0x00000008002e8f55 in std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::set_value() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x00000000002053e1 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::__execute() ()
#5  0x0000000000205763 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >*> >(void*) ()
#6  0x000000080025c776 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffc371a000

Thread 7 (LWP 100657 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080026a66c in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x000000080025e731 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x0000000800268388 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#3  0x000000080032de72 in std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x00000008002e971b in std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::wait() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#5  0x0000000000205389 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::__on_zero_shared() ()
#6  0x000000000020346b in func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&) ()
#7  0x0000000000206f18 in main::$_1::operator()() const ()
#8  0x0000000000206eed in void std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::__execute<>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<>) ()
#9  0x0000000000206ea5 in std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::operator()() ()
#10 0x0000000000206df3 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::__execute() ()
#11 0x0000000000207183 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >*> >(void*) ()
#12 0x000000080025c776 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#13 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffdf5f9000

Thread 6 (LWP 100656 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080026a66c in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x000000080025e731 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x0000000800268388 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#3  0x000000080032de72 in std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x00000008002e971b in std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::wait() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#5  0x0000000000205389 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::__on_zero_shared() ()
#6  0x0000000000207a22 in std::__1::__release_shared_count::operator()(std::__1::__shared_count*) ()
#7  0x00000000002044f4 in std::__1::future<void> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >(std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>&&) ()
#8  0x00000000002035ea in std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>::type>::type> std::__1::async<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>(std::__1::launch, func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0&&) ()
#9  0x0000000000203462 in func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&) ()
#10 0x0000000000206f18 in main::$_1::operator()() const ()
#11 0x0000000000206eed in void std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::__execute<>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<>) ()
#12 0x0000000000206ea5 in std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::operator()() ()
#13 0x0000000000206df3 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::__execute() ()
#14 0x0000000000207183 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >*> >(void*) ()
#15 0x000000080025c776 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#16 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffdf7fa000

Thread 5 (LWP 100655 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080026a66c in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x000000080025e731 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x0000000800268388 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#3  0x000000080032de72 in std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x00000008002e971b in std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::wait() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#5  0x0000000000205389 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::__on_zero_shared() ()
#6  0x0000000000207a22 in std::__1::__release_shared_count::operator()(std::__1::__shared_count*) ()
#7  0x00000000002044f4 in std::__1::future<void> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >(std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>&&) ()
#8  0x00000000002035ea in std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>::type>::type> std::__1::async<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>(std::__1::launch, func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0&&) ()
#9  0x0000000000203462 in func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&) ()
#10 0x0000000000206f18 in main::$_1::operator()() const ()
#11 0x0000000000206eed in void std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::__execute<>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<>) ()
#12 0x0000000000206ea5 in std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::operator()() ()
#13 0x0000000000206df3 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::__execute() ()
#14 0x0000000000207183 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >*> >(void*) ()
#15 0x000000080025c776 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#16 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffdf9fb000

Thread 4 (LWP 100654 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080026a66c in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x000000080025e731 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x0000000800268388 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#3  0x000000080032de72 in std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x00000008002e971b in std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::wait() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#5  0x0000000000205389 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::__on_zero_shared() ()
#6  0x0000000000207a22 in std::__1::__release_shared_count::operator()(std::__1::__shared_count*) ()
#7  0x00000000002044f4 in std::__1::future<void> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >(std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>&&) ()
#8  0x00000000002035ea in std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>::type>::type> std::__1::async<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>(std::__1::launch, func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0&&) ()
#9  0x0000000000203462 in func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&) ()
#10 0x0000000000206f18 in main::$_1::operator()() const ()
#11 0x0000000000206eed in void std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::__execute<>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<>) ()
#12 0x0000000000206ea5 in std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::operator()() ()
#13 0x0000000000206df3 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::__execute() ()
#14 0x0000000000207183 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >*> >(void*) ()
#15 0x000000080025c776 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#16 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffdfbfc000

Thread 3 (LWP 100653 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080026a66c in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x000000080025e731 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x0000000800268388 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#3  0x000000080032de72 in std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x00000008002e971b in std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::wait() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#5  0x0000000000205389 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::__on_zero_shared() ()
#6  0x0000000000207a22 in std::__1::__release_shared_count::operator()(std::__1::__shared_count*) ()
#7  0x00000000002044f4 in std::__1::future<void> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >(std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>&&) ()
#8  0x00000000002035ea in std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>::type>::type> std::__1::async<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>(std::__1::launch, func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0&&) ()
#9  0x0000000000203462 in func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&) ()
#10 0x0000000000206f18 in main::$_1::operator()() const ()
#11 0x0000000000206eed in void std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::__execute<>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<>) ()
#12 0x0000000000206ea5 in std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::operator()() ()
#13 0x0000000000206df3 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::__execute() ()
#14 0x0000000000207183 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >*> >(void*) ()
#15 0x000000080025c776 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#16 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffdfdfd000

Thread 2 (LWP 100652 of process 37763):
#0  0x000000080026a66c in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x000000080025e731 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x0000000800268388 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#3  0x000000080032de72 in std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x00000008002e971b in std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::wait() () from /usr/lib/libc++.so.1
#5  0x0000000000205389 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::__on_zero_shared() ()
#6  0x0000000000207a22 in std::__1::__release_shared_count::operator()(std::__1::__shared_count*) ()
#7  0x00000000002044f4 in std::__1::future<void> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >(std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>&&) ()
#8  0x00000000002035ea in std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>::type>::type> std::__1::async<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>(std::__1::launch, func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0&&) ()
#9  0x0000000000203462 in func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&) ()
#10 0x0000000000206f18 in main::$_1::operator()() const ()
#11 0x0000000000206eed in void std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::__execute<>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<>) ()
#12 0x0000000000206ea5 in std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::operator()() ()
#13 0x0000000000206df3 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::__execute() ()
#14 0x0000000000207183 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >*> >(void*) ()
#15 0x000000080025c776 in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#16 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffdfffe000

Thread 1 (LWP 100148 of process 37763):
#0  0x00000008004f984a in _nanosleep () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x000000080025f17c in ?? () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x000000080045fe0b in sleep () from /lib/libc.so.7
#3  0x0000000000203b7b in main ()
```

It seems lots of threads got stuck on `std::__1::condition_variable::wait`, which is unreasonable, in the test code, there is no use of any condition at all.

Can somebody tell me, am I doing it wrong or there is a bug in the std library?

---

Thanks. This example didn't fully mimic the actual behavior of my program. I simplified it too much.

Now I add vector of future, this is more like it:

```
void func2(std::atomic_long& n)
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> rs;
    for (auto i = 0L; i < 1000000000000L; ++i)
    {
        rs.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {add(n);}));
    }
    for (auto& r : rs)
    {
        r.wait();
    }
}
```

But it still got the same result:
On macOS, it was ok.

```
            29693311             29904143             29994992             29856976             30020535             29832796 
            29709344             29917687             30005488             29875611             30039727             29848932 
            29725334             29930826             30019428             29892350             30056678             29866293 
            29737403             29948258             30036760             29904964             30074102             29883648 
            29746597             29965134             30050115             29914459             30086189             29900767 
            29761543             29977363             30066833             29929475             30101723             29915059 
            29777678             29993381             30084101             29949095             30117847             29926040 
            29794253             30007301             30102985             29972819             30129613             29939935
```

On freebsd, it froze again:

```
               34079                29595                38239               508788                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               509103                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               509583                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               509808                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               510187                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               510543                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               510932                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               511616                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               512111                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               512952                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               514032                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               514205                30194                41242 
               34079                29595                38239               514577                30194                41242
```

Comment: Note that `std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {add(n);});` is not asynchronous because the return value is ignored as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654548/stdasync-doesnt-work-asynchronously).

Comment: It is almost certainly not a bug in the standard library implementation.

Comment: Yeah sounds like maybe you just wanted to start some threads?

Comment: I don't see why you would expect your `async` workers to work forever. They call the provided function which eventually finishes. The deadlock you see might just be the workers having finished.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Those workers should not have finished before incrementing the counter all the way to `1000000000000L`.

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38181

Comment: Given that you see the deadlock with old versions of CLang, I would expect that it has beed fixed somewhere between version 6.0.1 and version 11.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

You are not taking into account the return value of `std::async`, the future returned will block any execution until the end of the task you started with `std::async`. This program as written, it's not performing what you expect.
In addition you are calling std::async with recursion and it's not granted it will spawn a new thread, it can manage a pool so if the pool is busy you program can freeze apparently since the loop you are doing is really long. If you want more control you can use std::thread with std::packaged_task

Comment: Thanks. Yes, good point. The program didn't work as I expected. Actually, it was totally synchronized. The point it, if it is synchronized, it shouldn't freeze.